# confused about the definition of subgroup

Tags: linear-algebra, abstract-algebra

(2.1) Proposition. Let G be a group and let H be a nonempty subset of G. Then H is a subgroup if and only if the following two conditions are satisfied.
(1) If $a, b \in H$ then $a b \in H$.
(2) If $a \in H$ then $a^{-1} \in H$.

(2.2) Remarks. (1) Conditions (1) and (2) of Proposition 2.1 can be replaced by the following single condition.
$(1)^{\prime}$ If $a, b \in H$ then $a b^{-1} \in H$

Indeed, if $(1)^{\prime}$ is satisfied then whenever $a \in H$ it follows that $e=$ $a a^{-1} \in H$ and then $a^{-1}=e a^{-1} \in H .$ Thus $a \in H$ implies that $a^{-1} \in H$ Also, if $a, b \in H$ then $b^{-1} \in H$ so that $a b=a\left(b^{-1}\right)^{-1} \in H .$ Therefore, $(1)^{\prime}$ implies (1) and (2). The other implication is clear.

I do not understand the remark. Here is what I think. If (1)' is satisfied, whenever $a \in H$,we treat a as b, then $a a^{-1}$=$e\in H$, then using multiplication left cancelation law to get $a^{-1}=e a^{-1} \in H .$ Since $ b \in H$, the same reason to get $b^{-1} \in H$. b=$\left(b^{-1}\right)^{-1}$ for any $b \in H$(H is a group since it is a subgroup). Therefore, (1)′ implies (1) and (2). What is another implication

Comment: Well if (1) and (2) are satisfied, just use $ab \in H$ and $b^{-1}\in H$, so (1)' is fulfilled

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The other implication is that $(1)$ and $(2)$ together imply $(1')$. Indeed, if $a$ and $b$ belong to $H$, then by $(2)$ also $b^{-1}$ is in $H$, and by $(1)$ also $ab^{-1}$ is in $H$, which is condition $(1')$.

Comment: Could you help me check my thought？

Comment: Your thoughts are correct

Comment: @kade thanks！start with here is what I think is my thought。That part is correct？

Comment: Yes that part is correct :)

Comment: @kade thanks alot